# Foreach time the string is found in a database, display it

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreach, row

I would like to know how to have a foreach statement, where there is a variable called `$id`, which is a database value.

I would like to know how to make it so that the code tries to find every instance where a row  in a mysql database contains the value of the variable: `$id`, where it can be found multiple times.

Thanks, I have tried to explain this as well as possible.

Comment: Are you trying to compare that value against multiple columns in one table? Across more than one table in the DB?

Comment: How would more than one row have the same ID? IDs should be unique.

Comment: @Mike basically, it gets who posted a comment, with the ID of the one who posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM mytable
                  WHERE id='%s'",
 mysql_real_escape_string($id));

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query)
```